# How to remote control iphone from pc with clipboard support

Tags: iphone, controls, clipboard

I see iphone tutorials on youtube. They control their iphone from pc. How can I do that? Its important to have clipboard support so I can use copy/paste. My phone is jailbroken I installed Veency and I successfully controled my iphone from my pc but it was slow and I could not paste texts from pc.

example link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhnUDTjIfvE

Answer (score 0):

I think using shift+arrow keys on a VNC client to select text from your iPhone might allow you to use ctrl+c and ctrl+v to copy and paste.

Comment: shift+arrow keys didn't work for me. I downloaded reflector but it supports only iphone 4s and iphone 5. If anybody know another program which can control iphone remotly please share.